# Angular 2 FormBuilder, show all input fields and populate it with partial user data

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, underscore.js

Project is an Ionic 3 app, Angular 4.1.3, and Underscore 1.8.1.

I have a master list of user customizable fields, that is stored in the app. When user data comes from the server, we leave out any records that are blank - for efficiency.

My problem comes when I try to build repeated rows of input fields from the master list. All input fields should show regardless if the user has that particular information stored. Then, fill the input fields with the potentially incomplete user's data from the server.

STORED MASTER LIST OF FIELDS

```
"custom_fields":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"Company"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "name":"Job"
  }],
```

SAMPLE SERVER RESPONSE with missing data. Note missing company or job title.

```
"users":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "email":"email@domain.com",
     "fname":"User",
     "lname":"One",
     "department":2,
     "custom_fields":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "value":"ABC Company"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "email":"email2@domain.com",
     "fname":"User",
     "lname":"Two",
     "department":3,
     "custom_fields":[
        {
           "id":2,
           "value":"President"
        }
     ]
  } ]
```

I was thinking of extending the user's custom_fields with underscore, so the view has all fields regardless if the user has that info. Then subscribe only to the form changes.

But I'm sure there's an Angular2 FormBuilder trick to do this more elegantly. The fields are custom, so I won't know how many fields they might have. Thanks.

Comment: is there a way for you to get all the fields that a user can have?

Comment: Build your form based on the master list then...

Comment: @Sonicd300 Yep, I get all possible fields when the view is loaded - from localstorage.